# Composer update ended up saying Trait 'Carbon\Traits\Mixin' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I installed a new XAMPP with a higher version of PHP (7.2.21) on my windows machine and moved my Laravel project there. When I ran composer update in my project root everything went well but at the end it gave the following:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In Macro.php line 33:

  Trait 'Carbon\Traits\Mixin' not found


PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Carbon\Traits\Mixin' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Macro.php on line 33
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

I googled the error but found really nothing about this. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried removing the whole vendor folder and reinstalling with composer install?? This looks like a sort of bug during the update process.

Comment: please try `composer self-update` and only after `composer update`

Comment: @dparoli So you mean I have to update the composer itself before running `composer update`?

Comment: yes, composer is updated frequently and if it's some time you don't update composer and you have strange errors the firt think is to update composer itself

Comment: I ran `composer self-update`7 and it updated from version 1.7.3 tp 1.9.0 successfully. But when I ran `composer update` after that, I got the same last error! :(

Comment: You can try to remove `vendor/nesbot/carbon` and run `composer clearcache` and `composer update` but I am only guessing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should *update composer* itself with `composer self-update`, composer is updated frequently and it's better to have the latest version.

Then you can try to remove `vendor/nesbot/carbon` directory and run `composer clearcache` and `composer update`

Comment: Thanks, there is only one thing: I dont know why but I had to create the `framework` directory inside `storage` and create directories `sessions`, `views` and `cache` inside `framework`. Then everything worked well.

Comment: @RezaSaberi because those are expected to be present to write cache files and sessiosn in a fresh Laravel install, if you don't have them or the these don't have the correct permissions you would usually end up with an error with any interaction with the framework (artisan command or browser rendering or a route). Maybe those folders got deleted somehow while you were trying to fix your issue